# Longhorn backup/snapshot hooks

Tags: kubernetes, rancher, longhorn

How do I configure Longhorn backup so it executes some bash scripts in the pod before and after snapshot/backup is taken?

Something similar to Velero's backup hooks.

```
  annotations:
    backup.velero.io/backup-volumes: data
    pre.hook.backup.velero.io/command: "['/usr/bin/mysql', '-e', '\"flush tables with read lock;\"']"
    pre.hook.backup.velero.io/container: mysql
    post.hook.backup.velero.io/command: "['/usr/bin/mysql', '-e', '\"unlock tables;\"']"
    post.hook.backup.velero.io/container: mysql
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently not possible at the moment, according to the [longhorn github issue](https://github.com/longhorn/longhorn/issues/2164#issuecomment-756792572).

You can orchestrate similar behaviour by using [volume snapshot](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/volume-snapshots/)

```
kubectl exec mypod-id -- app_freeze
kubectl apply -f volumesnapshot.yaml
kubectl exec mypod-id -- app_thaw
```

Where `volumesnapshot.yaml` is:

```
apiVersion: snapshot.storage.k8s.io/v1
kind: VolumeSnapshot
metadata:
  name: my-longhorn-snapshot
spec:
  volumeSnapshotClassName: longhorn
  source:
    persistentVolumeClaimName: my-longhorn-pvc
```

See example for IRIS database: https://community.intersystems.com/post/amazon-eks-and-iris-high-availability-and-backup